# GitLab stopped sending repository notifications

Tags: gitlab

I'm using GitLab 7.4.3 (installed via Omnibus). A while ago it stopped sending notifications for repository events (like new commits pushed, merge requests, etc).

It's still sending notifications when I create a new user for example, so email configuration should not be the case. If I configure "Emails on push" service, it works as well.

I have my notifications settings set to "watch".

All processes are running. There are not stalled background jobs in Sidekiq, the counter is incrementing. Sidekiq.log looks like this:

`2014-12-02_13:18:51.50122 2014-12-02T13:18:51Z 26594 TID-b99ag PostReceive JID- INFO: start
2014-12-02_13:18:51.50124 2014-12-02T13:18:51Z 26594 TID-b99ag PostReceive JID- INFO: arguments: ["/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/gmdev/test.git", "key-1", "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0a08992c04ef657c25e0d355ad0618695fd1f2eb refs/heads/test2\n"]
2014-12-02_13:18:52.08550 2014-12-02T13:18:52Z 26594 TID-b99ag PostReceive JID- INFO: done: 0.584 sec`

It looks like DelayedMailer doesn't kick in. How can I debug this further though?

I tried restarting GitLab. I even upgraded it to the latest version recently, but it still won't work. It doesn't work after creating a new, fresh repository either.

I also configured Slack integration through a webhook. This doesn't work as well. (**EDIT**: After upgrading to 7.5.1 integration with Slack started to work. Still no emails though.)

Any help or tips much appreciated!

Comment: Are the shell hooks properly installed in the repos? `repositories/username/reponame.git/hooks` should be a symlink to `gitlab-shell/hooks` This is usually done automatically, but if you touch anything you shouldn't, including manual repo creation or moving shell around, it breaks.

Comment: Yep, the symlink is there: ``/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/gmdev/repo.git/hooks -> /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks``